Creating an admin page using observe() instead of observeEvent()
So currently I am trying to make an admin page for my shiny app. Previously I had a button labeled "Admin" and when clicked would take you to a login page by hiding all previous pages and showing just the admin-section + login-page. This method worked the issue is this required having the admin button on your screen at all times which is not clean, this is why I wanted to switch to a url detecting method. Essentially if I typed "?admin" at the end of my URL it would execute the same function as the button. The issue comes around when using observe() instead of observeEvent() as now when "?admin" is added at the end of the url it hides all previous pages but refuses to show the admin-section + login-page. Attempting to debug the login page does show but is classified as hidden still for some reason.
TLDR: Trying to switch from button to url based admin page but the process of changing from observeEvent() to observe() breaks the code.

Code for both methods below

Button Method:
    shiny::insertUI(
        selector = "body",
        where = "afterBegin",
        ui = htmltools::tags$div(
            id = "admin-button-container",
            style = "position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 10px; z-index: 1000;",
            shiny::actionButton("admin_button", "Admin")
        )
    )

    shiny::insertUI(
        selector = "body",
        where = "beforeEnd",
        ui = shinyjs::hidden(
            htmltools::div(
                id = "admin-section",
                class = "admin-section",
                htmltools::div(
                    id = "login-page",
                    htmltools::h2("Admin Login"),
                    shiny::passwordInput("adminpw", "Password"),
                    shiny::actionButton("submitPw", "Log in")
                )
            )
        )
    )

    shiny::observeEvent(input$admin_button, {
        shinyjs::runjs("hideAllPages();")
        shinyjs::show("admin-section")
        shinyjs::show("login-page")
    })


URL Method:
    insertUI(
        selector = "body",
        where = "beforeEnd",
        ui = shinyjs::hidden(
            div(
                id = "admin-section",
                class = "admin-section",
                div(
                    id = "login-page",
                    h2("Admin Login"),
                    passwordInput("adminpw", "Password"),
                    actionButton("submitPw", "Log in")
                ),
                shinyjs::hidden(
                    div(
                        id = "admin-content",
                        h2("Admin Page"),
                        actionButton("pause_survey", "Pause Survey"),
                        actionButton("pause_db", "Pause DB"),
                        downloadButton("download_data", "Download Data"),
                        actionButton("back_to_survey", "Back to Survey"),
                        hr(),
                        h3("Survey Data"),
                        DT::DTOutput("survey_data_table")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )

    #Observe for URL change
    observe({
        query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
        admin_query <- query[['admin']]
        show_admin <- !is.null(admin_query)

        if (show_admin) {
            shinyjs::runjs("hideAllPages();")
            shinyjs::show("admin-section")
            shinyjs::show("login-page")
        }
    })


Perhaps go back to your original method, but use uiOutput/ renderUI to display the admin button only when required. Use the same method to show/hide any other UI elements in the same way.

You changed many things between these two versions of the code, so it is hard to say why one works and the other doesn't.  In particular, the observe vs observeEvent is probably irrelevant.  You should only change one thing at a time so that it is easier to find the problem.  Also, if you provide a minimal working shiny app, then it is easier for people to help you.
